# Draw Custom shape Flutter Like This

Tags: flutter

i need to draw a shape like that using flutter [image: image that i want to draw shape like it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd might want to use a [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) with a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) for this.

Extend the `CustomPainter` and use `canvas.drawLine()` and `canvas.drawArc()` in its `paint` method. Maybe `canvas.drawPoints()` could work as well.

The two links contain videos on how to use these components.

```
CustomPaint(
  painter: MyCustomShapePainter(),
  // other properties
),

class MyCustomShapePainter extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawLine(...);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: how draw arc like the above